# My raw primitives cannot be displayed in Raymarching

Tags: glsl, shader, raymarching

I encountered a very strange problem while learning Raymarching.
My equation cannot be displayed well.
It can be displayed well in matlab. But it can't be shown on Shadertoy at all.

My equation：

```
f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2+z^2)^2+2*y*(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2*(x^2+z^2);
```

code in matlab:

```
f =@(x,y,z) (x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)^2+2*y*(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)+2*(x.^2+z.^2);
fimplicit3(f)
```

[matlab displays a normal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4I6W.png)

code in shadertoy：

```
float sdRound(vec3 p)
{
   float lengthXYZ = (p.x * p.x+p.y * p.y+p.z * p.z); 
   return lengthXYZ * lengthXYZ+2.0 * p.y * lengthXYZ+2.0 * (p.x * p.x+p.z * p.z);
}
```

I learned, practiced, and modified the iq code. (https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xds3zN).

But it cannot be displayed normally.
[Shadertoy displays abnormal pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weAt8.png)
[Shadertoy displays abnormal pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTTdC.png)

I don't know where the problem occurred. Please help me. Has troubled me for a long time.

Forgive my poor English. I use Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to lay in the very understanding of what raymarching is.
Your formula mathematically describes a surface (that is why it is displayed nicely in matlab), but this is not how raymarching works.
Defining an object for raymarching means defining a distance function for your object (which is different from a function mathematically describing its surface). These functions are identical for zero-returned values (which means coordinates are on the surface), but they are different for other values.
To create something similar to your object, I would suggest to explore the `sdRoundCone` method from [iq's Raymarching primitives](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xds3zN), as it seems the closest to what you want to achieve.